# How to upload files matching a pattern with aws cli to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Team, 
I need to upload all files matching this pattern console.X.log to s3, where X=0...any

I tried below and getting error.

```
aws s3 cp /var/log/console.* s3://test/dom0/

Unknown options: /var/log/console.70.log,s3://0722-maglev-avdc-provisions/dom0/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS s3 cli doesn't support regex, but there is an exclude and include for s3.
So you should be able to use:

```
aws s3 cp /var/log/ s3://test/dom0/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "console.*"
```

Note the order of the exclude and include, if you switch them around then nothing will be uploaded. You can include more patterns by adding more includes.

Comment: See: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX-style wildcards in a command's path arguments. However, most commands have `--exclude "<value>"` and `--include "<value>"` parameters that can achieve the desired result.

The following pattern symbols are supported.

- `*`: Matches everything.
- `?`: Matches any single character.
- `[sequence]`: Matches any character in the sequence.
- `[!sequence]`: Matches any character, not in the sequence.

Any number of these parameters can be passed to a command. You can do this by providing an `--exclude` or `--include` argument multiple times, e.g. `--include "*.txt" --include "*.png"`.

When there are multiple filters, the rule is the filters that appear later in the command take precedence over filters that appear earlier in the command.

For example, if the filter parameters passed to the command were `--exclude "*" --include "*.txt"`. All files will be excluded from the command except for files ending with `.txt` However if the order of the filter parameters was changed to `--include "*.txt" --exclude "*"`. All files will be excluded from the command.

This is a simple example to upload your source code to S3 and exclude the git files: `aws s3 cp /tmp/foo s3://bucket/ --recursive --exclude ".git/*"`

[Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)